# Are Canon EOS and Nikon DSLR lenses interchangeable?

Tags: canon, nikon, lens-mount

Can we use the lenses from, say a Canon EOS 550D kit (Canon EF-S 18-55mm) with a Nikon DSLR D5000 for example) ? Also, is the reverse possible ?

I'm looking at interchangeability between recent DSLR lenses only, and not with older lenses. Also, for "average" lenses, and not ultra wide/ultra zoom.

The reason for this question is that I'm trying to decide between a Nikon D5000 and a Canon EOS 500D. I like the Nikon better, but Canon is more popular here amongst people I can interchange lenses with :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nikon has the longest flange to focal-plane distance, so you can't use lenses meant for other 35mm lens-mounts on Nikon cameras (the lens would be too far from the sensor/film to focus to infinity). The exception might be if you were doing closeup/macro photography and didn't care about infinity focus. There are some medium-format lenses that can be adapted for use on Nikon cameras, though.

Canon has one of the shorter flange to focal-plane distances, so lenses for other mounts can more easily be adapted to Canon EOS (even with the extra spacing of the adapter in place, the lens is still close enough to the sensor/film to focus on infinity).

Adapting Nikon lenses to use on Canon cameras is a pretty common thing to do. For instance, lots of Canon shooters use adapters with Nikon's wide-angle lenses, which are particularly well-regarded.

One note about adapting Nikon lenses for use on Canon bodies. You'll either want to get the older lenses that have a physical aperture ring; or you'll need to get a special "G" adapter that allows you to set the shooting aperture on Nikon's 'G' lenses that have no physical aperture ring. Also, there's no adapter I know of that will work with Nikon's new PC-E lenses, since they have a completely different aperture control mechanism (currently only the three tilt/shift lenses are PC-E, though).

Another consideration is that adapted lenses are going to be completely manual-focus, and you may also lose in-camera metering (best you can hope for is probably spot- or center-weighted metering in manual exposure mode, maybe aperture mode if you're really lucky). So unless you have a specific reason for wanting to use a specific lens, it's probably not worth the trouble. I wouldn't recommend getting an adapter just so you can share lenses with friends. If all your friends shoot Canon and you want to be able to share lenses, you should go with a Canon DSLR.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I will stick with a Canon System :)

Comment: Good answer but it misses some information about crop factor (I think Nikkor DX lenses are not compatible with FF Canon Camera)

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's been done. [Novoflex](http://www.novoflex.com/en/products/adapters/adapter-finder/) has a Nikon to Canon adapter and, I think, for the other direction. However, unless it's optically corrected, you'll likely lose focus to infinity and, if it is optically corrected, you'll likely degrade the image quality. In general, you'll do better with lenses designed for your camera body.

Comment: Actually, no, when using Nikon lenses on Canon EF mount you do not lose focus to infinity. The mount opening is larger and the flange depth is only 44mm, so an adapter for Nikon lenses (depth: 46.5mm) can fit properly . In fact, a lot of mounts have a larger flange depth so there's room for an adapter, with noted exceptions Leica M and Canon FD.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to use an adapter. Plus there are a lot of other manufactures like Tamron, Sigma which provide good lenses for reasonable price for both Nikon and Canon.

Take look at the [Lens Comparison Guide](http://www.radiantlite.com/lens-guide)

Comment: +1 for the nice link. But Tamron, Sigma lenses are specific mounts, which are not interchangable once ordered, no ?

Comment: Yes, they produce specific lenses either for Canon and Nikon. But frankly speaking I don't get the idea why do you need this. Just compare list of your needs with what Canon and Nikon offer and what you friends have. I don't think that adapting lenses from Canon to Nikon (and vice versa) will give you good impact on image (or other advantages).